# How to group components properly

Tags: c#, forms, menu, devexpress, components

I am making an desktop app with Devexpress and Windows Forms. I have a principal form, which is a `IsMDIContainer`.

I have another 3 forms and I navigate between them with a menu. When I change the form, the components of the form which is going to be shown, look like this:

[image]

And after a few seconds, the form looks good. I have my components agruped in panels, but i dont know why is this is happening.
Anoyone knows what I have to do to dont hapend this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand WHAT is happening. You mention: "i dont know why is this is happening", but I don't know what you are referring to. Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

If your method for displaying the new form is declaring new controls and defining properties, you could try stopping the form that you're switching to from attempting to layout the controls until they're all correctly positioned.

Inside the method you are using to display the selected form, add the following:
`SuspendLayout()`

At the end of your form loading method, add the following:
`ResumeLayout()`

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) for an explanation.

This should allow the form to correctly set out its controls before rendering them to the monitor.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider voting it as your accepted answer, thank you.